# Function like array.length that doesn't include NULL elements?

Tags: java, arrays, null

```
TreeNode[] children = grid[row][col].getChildren();
```

I would like a simple function that can tell me how many objects are in this array? `getChildren()` will return an object of size no larger than 4, for example:

```
children[0] = null;
children[1] = TreeNode Object
children[2] = null;
children[3] = null;
```

Comment: So would you want `children.mySizeMethod()` to return 4 or 1 (or something else even)?

Comment: Consider using `List` or `Map` instead of a plain old array. The Collections API offers so many useful classes and methods.

Comment: (@BalusC - true ... but there's no "how many non-null elements" method ... assuming that is what he's asking.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Why don't you write it yourself:

```
public static <T> int getLength(T[] arr){
    int count = 0;
    for(T el : arr)
        if (el != null)
            ++count;
    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Code:

```
Arrays.stream(list).filter(e -> e != null).count();
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work. Essentially the same with the function written for you and not TreeNode specific.

```
int initLength(Object[] myArray) {
  int count = 0;
  for (Object obj : myArray) {
    if ( obj != null ) count++;
  }
  return count;
}
```

I called it initLength because those items are init'd but call it what you like. Some would say it's init'd when you define it, regardless of whether the contents are null.

Answer (score 1):

Other alternative:

```
ArrayList l = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(children));
l.removeAll(Collections.singleton(null)); 
l.size();
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps overkill to use predicates, but here's a Guava solution:

```
int numNotNull = Iterables.size( Iterables.filter( Arrays.asList( children ),
                        Predicates.notNull() ));
```

Answer (score 1):

In Java 8, you can use [Math.toIntExact](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#toIntExact-long-) and [Arrays.stream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#stream-T:A-) to construct a nice one-liner:

```
Math.toIntExact(Arrays.stream(row).filter(s -> s != null).count())
```

Comment: Does anyone know if this is better, performance wise, than writing a loop yourself?

Comment: Almost definitely not. Since the array is already allocated, you're not going to see any performance improvements from using a stream. Where this kind of thing really shines is when you're reading from an I/O stream like a file or socket (or some other kind of source which can be lazily read)

Comment: You can use `filter(Objects::nonNull)` instead of `filter(s -> s != null)`.